# MSAL authentication token issues

Tags: azure, azure-ad-msal, adal

I have integrated `MSAL` library in `iOS` to get the token and send to the our `backend` server for further use. we are using below code to get the token:

```
let kClientID = "xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxx" 
let kGraphEndpoint = "https://graph.microsoft.com/"
let kAuthority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxx"
let kScopes: [String] = ["user.read"]

let bundleID = Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier ?? "com.default.test"
let kRedirectUri = "msauth.\(bundleID)://auth"
```

Aquire Token code:

```
if let applicationContext = self.applicationContext, let webViewParameters = self.webViewParamaters {
            
    let parameters = MSALInteractiveTokenParameters(scopes: kScopes, webviewParameters: webViewParameters)
    parameters.promptType = .selectAccount
    
    applicationContext.acquireToken(with: parameters) { (result, error) in
        
        if let error = error {
            self.log(text: "Could not acquire token: \(error)")
            return
        }
        
        guard let result = result else {
            self.log(text: "Could not acquire token: No result returned")
            return
        }
        
        self.token = result.accessToken
        
        // calling graph API to get the name and user id ( Success )

        // sending this token to our API backend ( Failure 401 )
        

    }
}
```

**Problem:**
When Graph API is called from frontend `iOS` application after getting token,  it is working, and when we are sending same token to backend then it is not working getting `401 error`. The same token is not valid for backend application, but this was working Earlier when we were using `ADAL` Library in iOS application.

Is it because of Redirect URI ?? in ADAL we were using API endpoint as redirect and now we are using `"msauth.\(bundleID)://auth"` this format.

Please help.

Comment: You need to acquire 2 access tokens, one for MS Graph and one for your back-end. You do this by calling acquire token twice with different scopes. An access token is only valid for one API, they cannot be mixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Token you may have  received is only for MS Graph API, not your API ,As front-end acquires  access token for Microsoft Graph API.

In your front-end you need to specify scopes for your backend API as mentioned by @juunas.

> When your application needs to request an access token with specific permissions for a resource API, pass the scopes containing the app ID URI of the API in the format like this-> app ID URI/scope

From [MSdocs reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-acquire-cache-tokens), Some example scope values for different resources:

> Microsoft Graph API: https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read
>
> Custom web API:api://11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111/api.read

To set scopes in portal ,
go to the app registration of your API in Azure AD >  Expose an API> add a scope.
Azure AD should then give you a token that is meant for your API.

[SO reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61591804/validate-azure-bearer-token-from-frontend-on-net-core-webapi-backend)